# How to kill YARN job using RM REST API

Tags: curl, hadoop-yarn, kill

we have kerberos enabled EMR cluster. I would like to kill yarn jobs using RM API through an other application.

1. Do we have to enable kerberos on RM UI to make it work?.
2. How can we make a curl call with out enabling kerberos on RM UI ?